# azure function blob output binding parameter

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating this azure function in python, getting data from HTTP post and save to azure blob storage.

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, outputblob: func.Out[bytes]) -> func.HttpResponse:
# clientId = req.params.get("clientId")
clientId = os.environ["OS"]
# clientId = "abcdef"

req_body = req.get_json()

outputblob.set(json.dumps(req_body))
```

here is blob out binding part of function.json

```
    {
  "name": "outputblob",
  "type": "blob",
  "dataType": "binary",
  "path": "container/{clientId}/{datetime:yyyy}/{datetime:MM}/{datetime:dd}/{rand-guid}.json",
  "connection": "DatalakeConnectionStr",
  "direction": "out"
}
```

I tried 3 different option for parameter of **clientId**

- clientId = req.params.get("clientId")  <- from URL parameter, this
  one works
- clientId = os.environ["clientId"]  <- from configuration, this one not working
- clientId = "abcdef" <- this one not working

I really like to make os.environ["clientId"] one works. how to make it works.

Thanks,
Wes

Comment: Did you get the issue resolved? Actually, this is because we can not use ClientId in bindings. you can put this param in query or body of req that's why your first method is working fone and not others.

Comment: thank you, @sakulachi8, now I know for sure this does not works

Comment: what type of parameter is required for set method? I save a bytes object but the file seems empty.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You [Sakulachi8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6933873/sakulachi8) for your valuable suggestion and for pointing the OP in the right direction. Posting as an answer to help other community members.

> The first method failed because we cannot use ClientID in bindings, but you can use the ClientID in Query Parameters, or the body of the request will work.